# finding specific pattern in linux

Tags: linux

I want to find specific pattern in all the files in a directory and copy them to another line

For E.g
I want to find LOG_WARNING in one file XYZ and copy them to another file.

```
LOG_WARNING (abc, xyz,("WARNING:  Error in sending concurrent_ to pdm\n"));
```

command i have used is :

```
grep -rin "LOG_WARNING.*" file_name.c > output.txt
```

but it is not copying till the semicolon, please note that other texts are available in next line. I want to copy till ;(semi-colon)

Comment: `grep -o '^LOG_WARNING[^;]*' file.c > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`grep -rh "LOG_WARNING" * > out.txt`

This will match the pattern in all the files inside the directory. 
Since you mentioned that the texts that are present after the ';' are on the next line, I have provided this command. 
This will match the pattern and print the entire line, till the ';'.

Else,

try this

`grep -roPh 'LOG_WARNING[^;]*;' * > out.txt`